# when installing dconf editor, what does '-y' option meaning on ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

when you install, for example, dconf-editor,
you type,

```
sudo apt-get install -y dconf editor
```

What does -y options mean?

Comment: You know there's http://www.askubuntu.com ?

Comment: Please `man apt-get`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the -y flag used for in apt-get install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36873361/what-is-the-y-flag-used-for-in-apt-get-install)

Answer (score 1):

From the [man pages](http://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get):

> -y, --yes, --assume-yes
>
> Automatic yes to prompts. Assume "yes" as answer to all prompts and
> run non-interactively. If an undesirable situation, such as changing a
> held package or removing an essential package, occurs then apt-get
> will abort.

Answer (score 0):

In the command, `sudo apt-get install -y dconf editor` , it means that if the installation requires user to answer a yes/no question, assume it to be 'yes'.

View image e.g. https://taufanlubis.files.wordpress.com/2008/11/lsdev01.png

In general '-y' is a option used in many Linux terminal commands. 
[Details](http://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get):
-y, --yes, --assume-yes
    Automatic yes to prompts. Assume "yes" as answer to all prompts and run non-interactively. If an undesirable situation, such as changing a held package or removing an essential package, occurs then apt-get will abort.