# What is the -y flag used for in apt-get install?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line-interface, apt

What does the `-y` flag do when you're running `apt-get install`?

Example, from https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions:

```
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Comment: You're quoting the man page for the `less` command. For `apt-get`, the `-y` option assumes "yes" as the answer for all prompts.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question. Try [ubuntu.se].

Comment: Kk or we could move it... Thanks for pointing that out though I fixed that.

Comment: Yeah alright, but maybe someone else will be curious about this one day and it'll help them out.

Comment: @KirkM-saricDen you're right, thank you!

Comment: it helped me out right now :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It skips the confirmation of the installation. When you install a package, Ubuntu asks for confirmation (Y/N). With -y, Ubuntu does not ask.

Comment: Makes sense thank you :)